# How can I use this complex number in numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, complex-numbers

Here's the Python code I'm working on:

```
def inver_hopf(x,y,z):
    return (1/np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+(1+z)**2))*np.matrix([[1+z],[x+y.j]],dtype=complex)
```

The problem happens at `[x+y.j]`, where `j` means complex unit. It returns me the error message `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'j'`. If I remove the dot, then it returns `NameError: name 'yj' is not defined`. How can I correct that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`j` alone is a variable, you can have the complex number by typing `1j`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use `x` and `y` variables to write the complex number directly, try to pass then to the `complex` class. Example:

```
def inver_hopf(x, y):
    return np.matrix([complex(x, y)], dtype=complex)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to archive with your code.

In general writing `y.j`(`object.attribute`) you want to access the attribute of the said object. In your case the attribute `j` of the object `y` (an `int` in your example).

If i understand you correctly you want to have a matrix which first entry is pure real with value `1+z` and a second entry purely imaginary `x+y`. To get this you need to multiply the pure real sum `x+y` with `j`.

Which would result in:

```
def inver_hopf(x,y,z):
    return (1/np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+(1+z)**2))*np.matrix([[1+z],[(x+y)*1j]],dtype=complex)
```